# How to prevent user from removing lines from a file ( so he could only add lines,never remove)

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to fight my bad habit of wasting time on time-consuming websites such as reddit/liveleak etc.

The only thing which seems to work is adding a line like this to my etc/hosts 127.0.1.1 www.reddit.com

It works for a few days but then when i got nothing to do i edit this file and remove this line and start wasting my life again.

Is it a way to make my etc/hosts file immune to changes that would delete something from it ? (So that i would only be able to add things to it when i stumble upon a website which i think is a potential threat for my time)

It would be perfect if only way i could delete this hosts's immunity to deleting lines from it would be installing system once again,because i wouldnt do it just to browse reddit.

It is really important for me and i will be extremely grateful for any help.

Answer (score -2):

Do `chmod 644 /etc/hosts` on that file and also do `chmod root:root /etc/hosts`. Remove your account from `sudoers` file. Ask someone else to change `root password` so that you do not know it.

Keep in mind that it is you who can control you not some other way. Also this way you might face problems in some other tasks which require root privileges.